# add new form to desktop app VB.NET VS 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

This is my first application using VB.NET.

I am trying to add new windows form to my application. I followed the tutorials too but can't add the new form .

I am trying to add new form by right clicking in my `project -> add -> Form (Windows Form)`. But this form does not show `designer.vb` code. I do not know what am I doing wrong. I just want to create a new windows form like the default form created in the project. The default form created in the project has `designer.vb` and `resx` file.
When I try to add new form via *Project* menu, I can't find any of the icons that resemble to the icon of the default form Form1.vb.

Please see the attached image for details.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: After the "Add Form" command you'll get a dialog that lets you choose the type and name.  Make sure you *don't* pick the first item in the list, it has to be "Form".

Comment: Usually, when you select `Add-> Form (Windows Forms)`, in the dialog that appears, the correct template is already selected, so you clicked something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways:

Add->new->new item. You see this:

[image]

Then you get this:

[image]

So, from above, you select Form (windows form)

but, since creating a new form is "common"

Then you can use what you choose:

right click, add->Forms (windows form)

that will then launch the SAME screen as above, but WITH the forms already selected - hardly saves you much effort and time - but either way, you can then type in the form name - BUT BE CAREFULL!!! - WHAT you type in, if you change the extension, you will wind up creating somthing VERY differnt.

So, ONLY edit the name part, so when I do above, and choose forms (windows form), then I get this:

[image]

But ONLY edit the text "form1" and do NOT change, or mess with the .vb that follows.

So, I can chose (set) the form name to MyCoolForm like this

[image]

So, don't put spaces in the name, and LEAVE alone the .vb part. That is also imporant.

Now, hit add,

[image]

and you should see this:

[image]